# Number of ways to collect ticket

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are 5 people with \$$5$ each and $5$ people with \$10 each such that they are in a bus stop.A ticket collector has to collect tickets from them and he has no change initially.The ticket collector maintains a log book for this.The number of ways in which he can collect the tickets?

Is the data in this question sufficient? Shouldn't there be price of ticket be mentioned in the question? Please explain the question if data is sufficient.

Comment: This is given by the catalan number $C_{10}$, which is equal to $\binom{10}{5}/6$

Comment: The price of the ticket is most likely $5$ dollars.

Comment: In fact, if the price is more than $5$ dollars then some of the follows in the line would not be able to afford the ticket (people do not make lines for things they can't buy). If the ticket costs less than $5$ dollars then it is impossible to make the transaction regardless of the ordering). We conclude the price is $5$ dollars for the problem to make sense.

Comment: @TheKindCat So for five people with $\$5$ there would be only 1 way to collect the ticket?

Comment: yeah, unless you consider the people to be distinct, in which case the answer would be $5!$ when there are $5$ people with $5$ bucks and the answer would be $\binom{10}{5}/6\times 5!^2$ for the case in the original post.

Comment: @TheKindCat Could you explain a bit as how is it analogous to Catalan number?

Comment: The wikipedia page on catalan numbers covers it quite nicely. It has a long list of things that can be enumerated with catalan numbers

Comment: @TheKindCat Yes I saw wiki but not quite able to relate.Why are we taking n=5 here?